# VHDL How to add a std_logic_vector with a std_logic signal together?

Tags: vhdl

I've got

```
douta   : in    std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
doutb   : in    std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
c0  : in    std_logic;
f1  : in    std_logic;
f0  : in    std_logic;
res : out   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
```

I'm trying to build a simple ALU, and one of the functions this ALU provides is 
when

```
f1 and f0 both = 1 
res = douta plus b plus c0
```

so I wrote

```
f1 = '1' and f0 = '1' then res <= douta + doutb + c0;
```

but obviously its not gonna work because the datatype of `douta` and `doutb` is `std_logic_vector` where as `co` is just `std_logic`

and I got this error when compile

```
' Error 603 line 34 : Incompatible types for arithmetic operator: LHS=std_logic_vector!18, RHS=std_logic
```

any idea how I can fix this problem ?

**edit:**
also have tried

```
f1 = '1' and f0 = '1' then res <= douta + doutb + ("000" & c0);
```

but still no luck, this time the compiler says

```
LHS=std_logic_vector!7, RHS=array_1_of_std_logic_3_d_0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think I found a fix, need to add the following library

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

and what we tried will work :) Thanks to @jdehaan

Comment: Please don't use std_logic_vector if you're going to do arithmetic on them. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Please don't use `std_logic_vector` if you're going to do arithmetic on them.  Use `ieee.numeric_std`, and use the `signed` or `unsigned` types. Then you can just add your '0' or '1' to it.

The workaround of using `std_logic_arith.all` is a fudge using a non-standard library, which can get you into portability troubles when you change toolchains.

I wrote a more detailed page on this: http://parallelpoints.com/node/3

There was some discussion on this on comp.lang.vhdl here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.vhdl/browse_thread/thread/549e1bbffd35914d/83cc0f19350fc392?hl=en&q=group:comp.lang.vhdl+numeric_std#83cc0f19350fc392 and also in the comp.lang.vhdl FAQ.

Comment: +1 for the link to your parallelpoints post. If I were teaching, I'd make it mandatory reading for all my students.

Comment: Thanks @rick!  I gave a lecture to some undergrad EEs who were just starting out with FPGAs, and hammered on that for a short while :)

Answer (score 1):

You could transform c0 into a std_logic_vector. It has been a long time since I made VHDL...

```
if f1 = '1' and f0 = '1' then
 if c0 = '1' then
   res <= douta + doutb + "0001";
 else
   res <= douta + doutb;
 end if;
end if;
```

This is probably not so performant, maybe the silicium compiler synthesizes it so something good, maybe it's a better idea to write it so that c0 is modified into a vector and then add all three douta, doutb and the converter c0. Another option would be to do the calculations bit for bit but then what do you have the compiler for?

It may sound ridiculous but sometimes the compiler produces a better result if you give it some hints like this (just try it out and verify the output, by such a small example not a big deal):

```
if f1 = '1' and f0 = '1' then
 if c0 = '1' then
   res <= douta + doutb + "0001";
 else
   res <= douta + doutb + "0000";
 end if;
end if;
```

Another advice, if you write if's and the results are somewhat strange, introduce an else to fix the undecided states (some compilers behave badly if they have too much freedom!). But that's from my experience that is already getting back to year 2004!!!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, yes I tried this 

f1 = '1' and f0 = '1' then res <= douta + doutb + ("000" & c0);

but again I thought just make up the missing bits with all 1 but it doesn't work the compiler says

 Incompatible types for arithmetic operator: LHS=std_logic_vector!7, RHS=array_1_of_std_logic_3_d_0

I guess I will give your idea a try !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the std_logic to a std_logic_vector to do the addition.  Just do the addition as is, and make sure that "res" has enough bits to hold the max answer.  In this case res needs to be 5 bits wide in order for it to now overflow.

And as a style nit, don't name your input ports "dout".  That's bad form.  Call them din here, because that's what they are.  And in the architecture than instantiates this you connect another component's output port named "dout" to the "din" of this component.